# Is there anyway to copy git repo from one EC2 instance to another EC2 instance using Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have 3 Instances in AWS one is dev, staging and build server instance. If I build staging branch in build server. How can I copy the repo to another EC2 instance such staging server from build server?

Comment: I suspect you need to clarify your question to get an answer that will help. This is not a Jenkins problem (as defined by the tags). The simplest way would be to use scp. `scp -r user@your.server.example.com:/path/to/drop/location ${WORKSPACE}/`

Comment: Why would you need the whole repo? You can selectively `stash` your artifacts from the build node and then `unstash` them in the dev and staging nodes.

Comment: thanks towel I am trying to prepare jenkins pipeline for react app.. i have checked stash...